# Does PayPal IPN used in a mobile app still require paypal approval?

Tags: mobile, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a Unity Mobile app that has a web UI that we are using PayPal IPN. I was wondering if anyone knows if PayPal has to approve the app before it goes live if its using IPN and not the mobile SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to use IPN, you do not need any approval from PayPal. All you need to have is a PayPal account and some integration with the IPN listener. From there you are good to go with the IPN. I hope I answered to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the info